# PostgreSQL on Corda enterprise node throws relation errors

Tags: postgresql, corda

Running corda enterprise with PostgreSQL in docker container. I have followed the instruction in docs and have set database schema. On database start I see the following errors. Can anyone help what is going on there?

```
2018-10-11 06:57:57.491 UTC [1506] ERROR:  relation "node_checkpoints" does not exist at character 22
2018-10-11 06:57:57.491 UTC [1506] STATEMENT:  select count(*) from node_checkpoints
2018-10-11 06:58:22.440 UTC [1506] ERROR:  relation "corda-schema.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
2018-10-11 06:58:22.440 UTC [1506] STATEMENT:  select count(*) from "corda-schema".databasechangeloglock
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, did yo manage to solve it? I'm using the `public` schema for everything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the database user name and schema name don't have the same value, ensure that correct default schema is set for the user by running as database administrator:

```
ALTER ROLE "[USER]" SET search_path = "[SCHEMA]";
```

Other possible issue is to mixing upper/lower case and other characters in schema name, could you ensure that schema name has all lower cases (e.g. corda-schema and not CORDA-SCHEMA or Corda-Schema).