# Corda 4.7 with Postgres throws exception when making changes on states

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-migration, corda

I am facing an issue when using `postgres` as a `database` for `Corda 4.7`.

Everything is run using `Docker`.

**Context**

What I did was:

1. Add the `postgres` config to the `node.conf`

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db_name"
    dataSource.user = user
    dataSource.password = password
    maximumPoolSize = 10
    connectionTimeout = 50000
}
```

2. Run the `postgres` Docker image with the following env variables:

```
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        - POSTGRES_USER=user
        - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
```

All `network` parameters are set correctly and `Corda` is able to connect to the `DB`.

3. Put the Cordapps in the cordapps folder
4. Run Corda migration using :

```
run-migration-scripts --app-schemas --core-schemas
```

The persistence file is created correctly and in the execution logs I have:

```
Database migration scripts for core and app schemas complete. There are no outstanding database changes.
```

However, in the `postgres` instance, I see the following logs:

```
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.352 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.352 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5442
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.352 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5442
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.358 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5442"
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.364 UTC [75] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-02-18 13:18:29 UTC
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:29.368 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:42.820 UTC [82] ERROR:  relation "node_checkpoints" does not exist at character 22
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:42.820 UTC [82] STATEMENT:  select count(*) from node_checkpoints
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:46.694 UTC [82] ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
postgres_node2_1  | 2021-02-18 13:18:46.694 UTC [82] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock
```

5. Run Corda node with all the files and folders `mapped` to the docker image.

**Application**

So, my application, for simplifying things, has three `flows`:

- `RegisterState` : Creates a new `state` with some data
- `RetrieveState` : Checks the database for the `state` identified by a primary key and returns it
- `ModifyState` : Checks for the `state`, modify its data then commit it again.

And a `WebServer` connected via `RPC` to the `Corda` node.

I start by running the `RegisterState` flow and it works just fine. I log into the db and I see that the data is there. Everything is fine until now.

I then run the `RetrieveState` flow to get a device identified by its primary key. And this also works just fine.

**Issue**

Now, when I execute the `ModifyState` flow. It keeps **hunging** forever.

- I check using `flow watch` from the `node shell` and I see the flow as `pending`.
- I check the `postgres` logs and I only see the logs from earlier (step 4 in the Context)

On the Corda logs side, we have the following logs:

```
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:52,522Z [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] network.NetworkMapUpdater. - Fetched: 11 using 16 Threads in 29ms
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,556Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - No need to notarise this transaction. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=OU=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocatio
n_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, sess
ion_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=95C569C0EF81236C607B378E55F6A8A54C56BD9F83406FD74956B8426CAB3F11}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,556Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Recording transaction locally. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=OU=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5d
aced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_tim
estamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=95C569C0EF81236C607B378E55F6A8A54C56BD9F83406FD74956B8426CAB3F11}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,715Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Recorded transaction locally successfully. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=95C569C0EF81236C607B378E55F6A8A54C56BD9F83406FD74956B8426CAB3F11}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,715Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - All parties received the transaction successfully. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=95C569C0EF81236C607B378E55F6A8A54C56BD9F83406FD74956B8426CAB3F11}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,982Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - No need to notarise this transaction. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=64CA2ABEA6CE7F33DD770947A6D7A549944ED634383979EDB117D3B02A246C39}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:53,982Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Recording transaction locally. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=ff, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=64CA2ABEA6CE7F33DD770947A6D7A549944ED634383979EDB117D3B02A246C39}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:54,010Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Recorded transaction locally successfully. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=64CA2ABEA6CE7F33DD770947A6D7A549944ED634383979EDB117D3B02A246C39}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:54,010Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - All parties received the transaction successfully. {actor_id=corda, actor_owning_identity=<identity>, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f91758aa-bf8d-44d2-839e-f712c052fd88, invocation_id=5daced37-40c9-4d1a-a617-9b997c6a6c69, invocation_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:25:52.396Z, origin=corda, session_id=2616aa0f-610c-4000-a149-205e300a449b, session_timestamp=2021-02-18T11:23:50.639Z, thread-id=212, tx_id=64CA2ABEA6CE7F33DD770947A6D7A549944ED634383979EDB117D3B02A246C39}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:54,562Z [NetworkMapUpdateDBInsertThread-1] network.PersistentNetworkMapCache. - Adding node with info: NodeInfo(addresses=[<ip>], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[OU=<identity>], platformVersion=9, serial=1612475291755), owningKey=DLHqo6EenXkBvj7EXxpNu4e5rUALshtdSjSNuuZeGPNzVc




....



[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:59,273Z [Thread-18 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] bridging.BridgeControlListener. - Received bridge control message Create(nodeIdentity=<identity>, bridgeInfo=BridgeEntry(queueName=internal.peers.DL6pRbUitK9BcuaDxuEE2wanonM5s8Prig7cLJisAnSmqc, targets=[<ip>], legalNames=[OU=<identity>], serviceAddress=false))
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:59,311Z [Thread-18 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] bridging.AMQPBridgeManager$AMQPBridge. - Create new AMQP bridge {legalNames=<identity>, maxMessageSize=10485760, queueName=internal.peers.DL6pRbUitK9BcuaDxuEE2wanonM5s8Prig7cLJisAnSmqc, source=<identity>, targets=<ip>}
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:59,312Z [Thread-18 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] netty.AMQPClient. - Connect to: <ip>:10102
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:25:59,396Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient. - Failed to connect to <ip>:10102
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /<ip>:10102
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
[INFO ] 2021-02-18T11:26:00,399Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient. - Retry connect to <ip>:10102
```

However, on the `Notary`, there are no logs concerning this very transaction.

**Questions**

- Why do I see those postgres logs when running the migration ?
- Did I miss something in the `configuration` of the DB?
- I noticed that the `postgres` section in the `Corda 4.5 Documentation` disapeared in `4.7`. Is that normal ?

**Extra**

We tried looking the problem and we found the following [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755787/postgresql-on-corda-enterprise-node-throws-relation-errors). However, we tried applying the answer but it didn't work in our case.

Thank you so much

Comment: The issue was connectivity to the Notary... was broken for some reason. Everything works fine currently. Will leave the question here so that people who are also configuring Postgres for Corda 4.7 have an idea of the steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Connectivity to the notary of course is huge for a network, although it is surprising to hear that it was a connectivity issue that caused the Postgres error you were seeing.

in any event glad to hear you were able to figure it out!

Comment: We still see those logs on Postgres. But so far, everything is working as expected. 
Maybe, those ERRORs will give us hard times sometimes later.